# Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by curl_exec()

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I have seen some similar SO questions, but they did not solve my issue.

When I perform a cUrl GET, I am getting an error message:

```
Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by
".../cUrlWrapper.php" at line 60.
```

The corresponding PHP code is:

```
$this->curl = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($this->curl);  // Line 60
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how I could solve this?

**Solution Update**

Although the approved solution solved my issue (workaround), I also removed an unnecessary `ContainerAwareTrait` in a service (root cause of my issue) which is even better in the first place.

Comment: session_start() have to be start of the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you set the "return transfer" option, `curl_exec()` will *output* the result of the URL request. Once that output has happened, you cannot set any new headers, like starting a session.

You can either call `session_start()` **before** you include the `cUrlWrapper.php` file (or call whatever function that `curl_exec()` is in), *or* you can catch the result of the URL request and output it later:

```
$this->curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($this->curl);
// perhaps "return $result;" if this is in a function

// ...
session_start();
// ...

echo $result;
```

Comment: Makes sense, you can not output anything before starting the session.

Comment: I have set a session_sart() after setting my options and before my curl_exec() and the exception has disappeared. Thanks !